# Iterate over the options in a HTML select with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I got this example from a blog, but every time I do this:

```
$(':input[name=' + inputName + ']').each(function(i, selected)
{
    alert($(selected).text());
});
```

I got all an alert with all the options together :(

I have to search by the input name always, the inputs have no id.

Which is the right way to do it?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `select` tag is found by jquery, not `option` tags

This will give you list of the options.

```
$(':input[name=' + inputName + '] option').each(function(i, selected) {
    alert($(selected).text());
});
```

[An example](http://jsfiddle.net/CCCnz/)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your html, try this:

```
$(":input[name='" + inputName + "'] option").each(function(i, selected) {
    alert($(selected).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your HTML is similar to this

```
<SELECT NAME="mylist">
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</SELECT>
```

you need to modify your selector to iterate over the `<OPTION>` tags, your selector was iterating over the `<SELECT>` tag

```
var inputName = mylist;
$(':input[name=' + inputName + '] option').each(function(i, selected)    {
        alert($(selected).text());
});
```